# Rspec should_receive expectation different behaviour in Sinatra and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, sinatra, rspec2

So, let's consider we have two models, A1 and A2, and A1 has_many A2, while A2 belongs_to A1. According to the ActiveRecord Spec, if you instantiate from A1, and try to create a resource in the a2 collection, it triggers an exception, saying the parent needs to be saved in order for it to be saved:

```
a1 = A1.new
a1.a2s.create #=> BOOM! Exception
```

Til here, all clear. But now I have an Rspec test for the case, in which I have an unsaved A1 instance, and then I do:

```
a1.a2s.should_receive(:create)
a1.a2s.create
```

And this is where the milk turns sour. I have these AR Models replicated in a Sinatra app and a Rails App. When I run it in Rails, the spec runs, since the expectation was matched, even though it raised an Exception. In Sinatra, though, it just raises the Exception, not accepting the test.

Can someone tell me why? I thought it was an Rspec issue, but they don't acknowledge it as such.

Comment: The spec should not raise an exception since `should_receive` captures the call to the method and doesn't trigger it

Comment: but that is exactly what is happening in the Sinatra case. Can you tell me where does this capture of the exception exactly happens?

Comment: Provide the code you're testing (model or controller), I'll give you the proper spec

Answer (score 0):

How are you storing your data in the Sinatra app?

In ActiveRecord, `a1.a2s` gives you the same `ActiveRecord::Relation` instance both times, so the expectation is bound to the instance that calls `create`.

My guess is that in Sinatra `a1.a2s` is returning a new instance each time it's called, so the expectation is not bound to the caller of `create`.

You could test my theory by running

```
a1.a2s.object_id
a1.a2s.object_id
```

and seeing if both ids are the same.